# Casting generic COM object to a specific .NET class

Tags: c#, com, casting, type-conversion

I'm not a C# programmer so excuse me if it's a silly question, but I can't find any solutions.

I have an `Object`. It's a COM object and its `ToString()` returns "System.__comObject". When examining its inner contents with debugger I can see that this object has a property called `Object` and it's an instance of the actual class that I want. However, `Object` class has no property `Object`, and when I'm trying to cast the object itself to the desired type I get an exception. How should COM object be converted to a .NET object?

Comment: You can't, the best you can do is cast it to an interface that matches one of the COM interfaces that object implements

Comment: @Mgetz: how can I found what interfaces it implements?

Comment: Your question seems to indicate you have access to the native code, if that's the case you can look at the objects native declaration. But if you can I would highly suggest using [Tlbimp to create a .NET library to do the interop for you.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6tx9dw3.aspx)

Comment: @Mgetz: no, it's Microsoft library and it's very poorly documented. I certainly don't have the declaration for this object. In fact, I can only guess it's type, which is exactly what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Which library? It may already have a Primary Interop Assembly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know what type you'd like it to be, you could set up a method to convert it yourself, using `dynamic` to access the properties:

```
public static MyObject ConvertFromComObject(dynamic comObject)
{
    return comObject.Object;
}
// or, if that doesn't work:
public static MyObject ConvertFromComObject(dynamic comObject)
{
    return new MyObject { MyProperty = comObject.Object.MyProperty };
}
// or maybe
public static MyObject ConvertFromComObject(dynamic comObject)
{
    return new MyObject { MyProperty = comObject.MyProperty };
}
```

Comment: This works, thanks a lot! Can I make it work in-line, without a standalone method?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Yes of course. Just cast to `dynamic`, e.g. `MyObject myObj = ((dynamic)comObject).Object;`, or declare your `comObject` as `dynamic` from the start: `dynamic comObject = SomeCom.GetObject(); comObject.Object.DoSomething();`.